# Want to render different values at different time in react formik

Tags: reactjs, if-statement, render, formik

I want to render a value if my Id is true if the Id is false the value shouldnt exist, is it possible to render what values formik

```
initialValues={{
                        id:currentBankData.id || '',
                        name: currentBankData.name || '',
                        address: currentBankData.address || '',
                        country: currentBankData.country || '',
                        region: currentBankData.region || '',
                        city: currentBankData.city || '',
                        swiftCode: currentBankData.swiftCode || '',
                        routeCode: currentBankData.routeCode || '',
                        
                        //Example want to do something like this
    if(Id){
        imageBinairyData: currentBankData.image ||'' ,
    }else{
    image: currentBankData.image || '',
    }
                    }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
//Example want to do something like this
  [Id ? 'imageBinairyData' : 'image']: currentBankData.image || '',
```

So your code may look like

```
initialValues={{
  id:currentBankData.id || '',
  name: currentBankData.name || '',
  address: currentBankData.address || '',
  country: currentBankData.country || '',
  region: currentBankData.region || '',
  city: currentBankData.city || '',
  swiftCode: currentBankData.swiftCode || '',
  routeCode: currentBankData.routeCode || '',
  [Id ? 'imageBinairyData' : 'image']: currentBankData.image || '',
}}
```

Comment: Can you set values  = to each other like routeCode = swiftCode

Comment: @ChrisJnrPotgieter, didn't get you. Can you provide more details please?

Comment: I know Im suppose to use formikcontext something like this  setTest(captureForm.values.imageBinairyData.data);

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could do something like this:

```
<Form
  initialValues={{
    id:currentBankData.id || '',
    name: currentBankData.name || '',
    address: currentBankData.address || '',
    country: currentBankData.country || '',
    region: currentBankData.region || '',
    city: currentBankData.city || '',
    swiftCode: currentBankData.swiftCode || '',
    routeCode: currentBankData.routeCode || '',
    imageBinairyData: !Id ? undefined : currentBankData.image || '' ,
    image: Id ? undefined : currentBankData.image || '',
  }}
/>
```

Or you can simply create the values conditionally before passing in:

```
render () {
  const initialValues = {
    id:currentBankData.id || '',
    name: currentBankData.name || '',
    address: currentBankData.address || '',
    country: currentBankData.country || '',
    region: currentBankData.region || '',
    city: currentBankData.city || '',
    swiftCode: currentBankData.swiftCode || '',
    routeCode: currentBankData.routeCode || '',
  };
  if (Id) {
    initialValues.imageBinairyData = currentBankData.image || '';
  } else {
    initialValues. image = currentBankData.image || '';
  }

  return <Form initialValues={initialValues} />
}
```

Comment: how do you pass the values to the existing initial values

Comment: could you elaborate - what do you mean by "pass the values to the existing initial values"?

Comment: like the initial values I have above ,is their a way to render the values then add them